# Convert string to array inside table

Tags: php, arrays, string

i have string that will produce table, but i want to know how to make this one column into list.

```html
$display_string = "<center><table border = 1>";
$display_string .= "<tr>";
$display_string .= "<th>Name</th>";
$display_string .= "<th>REGION</th>";
$display_string .= "<th>PTT</th>";
$display_string .= "<th>Exchange</th>";
$display_string .= "<th>User Post</th>";
$display_string .= "<th>Post</th>";
$display_string .= "<th>Email</th>";
$display_string .= "<th>Contact Number</th>";
$display_string .= "</tr>";

// Insert a new row in the table for each person returned
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   $display_string .= "<tr>";
   $display_string .= "<td>$row[User_Nama]</td>";
   $display_string .= "<td>$row[User_REGION]</td>";
   $display_string .= "<td>$row[User_PTT]</td>";
   $display_string .= "<td>$row[User_Exchange]</td>";
   $display_string .= "<td>$row[User_Desc]</td>";
   $display_string .= "<td>$row[SubType]</td>";
   $display_string .= "<td>$row[User_Email]</td>";
   $display_string .= "<td>$row[User_Phone]</td>";
   $display_string .= "</tr>";
}

//echo "Query: " . $query . "<br />";
$display_string .= "</table></center>";

echo $display_string;
```

i want this column to show the output in List.
     $display_string .= "$row[User_Exchange]";
but i dont know how to do it.

Thank you in advance.

i forgot to put my output.

i cannot show the image
so here is my output:

---

### |  Exchange   |

### |_MTM_BRF_BNR |

### |_DM_MTM_BRF  |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `$row['User_Exchange']` is an array of strings like **_MTM_BRF_BNR**, you can do:

```
$display_string .= "<td><ul>";
foreach($row['User_Exchange'] as $user_exchange){
$display_string .= "<li>" .$user_exchange ."</li>";
}
$display_string .= "</ul></td>";
```

If `$row['User_Exchange']` is a string separated with underscores, you can create an array from that using `explode()` then create the list like:

```
$user_exchange = array_filter(explode('_', $row['User_Exchange']) );
$display_string .= "<td><ul>";
foreach($user_exchange as $exchange){
$display_string .= "<li>" .$exchange ."</li>";
}
$display_string .= "</ul></td>";
```

you will get:

- MTM
- BRF
- BNR

Comment: please quote array keys

Comment: @mdodong  i have tried this but its not working.

Comment: @soul , what is the output of `print_r($row['User_Exchange'])` ?

Comment: @mdodong i have edited my post. down there is my output. i want to put an image but i am not allowed. so just imagine that is the table.

Comment: @soul , your output does not show much information to work with your problem. Is there any other way you can show us what is the current output of your table and what you expect to show?

Comment: @mdodong erm. okay. here is the output for the first row " _MTM_BNR ". i have this kind of output.

Comment: Is this the output of  `"<td>$row['User_Exchange']</td>";`  ?

Comment: @mdodong yes it is. sorry if i am not making this clear.

Comment: So what your telling me is that the `$row['User_Exchange']` is a string with underscore and you want to output the items in between the underscores as a list?

Comment: @mdodong i still can not get the solution. am i doing right?

$User_Exchange = array_filter(explode('_', $row['User_Exchange']) );
$display_string .= "<td><ul>";
foreach($User_Exchange as $exchange){
$display_string .= "<li>" .$exchange ."</li>";
}
$display_string .= "</ul></td>";
$display_string .= "</table></center>";

echo $display_string;

Comment: just put my code as replacement for your `$display_string .= "<td>$row[User_Exchange]</td>";` , the rest of the code stays the same.

Comment: @soul no problem, just returning the favor as I have found a lot of help from *SO* when I was still starting with PHP...

Comment: @mdodong great! i should remember that!

Answer (score 0):

If the list is delimited by the _ underscore character, then you could use a simple string replace:

```
$display_string .= '<td>'.str_replace('_', ', ', ltrim($row['User_Exchange'], '_')).'</td>';
```

ltrim should take care of the initial underscore.

If you want an array, use explode to split the string by another string (underscore):

```
explode('_', $row['User_Exchange'])
```

http://php.net/explode